# Convert Array with a object to array Jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I have this array

```
var Obj = 
 [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John",
            "score": 4300,
            "active": 1,
        }];
```

I want to convert it to this

```
var dataSet = [
    ['1','John','4300','1']
];
```

I have tried a lot of simple jquery but no luck, soory for this if you think it is simple, but i am new in JS

Comment: That's not JSON, that's an array containing an object. Even if you got the data as JSON (at some point) it's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Do you care what order the elements in the inner array are in?

Comment: No i dont need order because i use that array in datatables, there is sorting event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the values regardless of the keys, you can use the [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffor...in) syntax:

```
var dataSet = Obj.map(function(x) { 
    var result = []; 
    for (key in x) {
        result.push((x[key]||"").toString());
    }
    return result; 
});
```

It looks like `array.map` doesn't work in IE8 and below, so [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) is a similar alternative if you need old browser compatibility.

Comment: Are you using IE8 or below?

Comment: Edited to make the values strings. It does exactly what you're asking for. If this isn't what you wanted, you'll need to modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's no jQuery involved. jQuery is for dealing with document objects.

Here's a solution which arranges the items in the given example order, and converts all the values to strings:

```
function convert(objectList) {
  return objectList.map(function(x) {
    return [""+x.id, ""+x.name, ""+x.score, ""+x.active];
  });
}

var Obj = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "score": 4300,
    "active": 1,
  }
];
console.log( convert(Obj) );
```

Comment: Now works, txanks, but as you may see i have ID NAME SCORE ACTIVE hardcoded, what if i have diferrent structure?

Comment: You could change the convert function. Do you expect to get objects at run-time with arbitrary properties? How would you order arbitrary properties?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should give your desired result assuming you have an array of objects.

```
var JsonObj = 
[{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John",
            "score": 4300,
            "active": 1,
        }];
var dataSet = [];

for(var i=0; i<JsonObj.length; i++){

  var innerDataSet = []
  for(prop in JsonObj[i]){
    innerDataSet.push(""+JsonObj[i][prop]);
  }

  dataSet.push(innerDataSet);
}
```

If you are trying to convert to JSON or back, take a look at [JSON.stringify(text)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse(text)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: I realized you have strings in your example array. Looking at @AgentME's cast to a string, does this work for you?